# How to debug dockerfiles when using gcloud and google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, docker, pycharm, gcloud

I am using Google App Engine and PyCharm 4.0.4 and GCloud managedvm.

I am attempting to access more information about the building of my dockerfile than is given by console output when running locally using dev_appserver.py .

[medusavm](https://github.com/rahul080327/medusa) is a python linux console app that can convert python code to dart code, among other functionalities.

In my dockerfile, [medusavm](https://github.com/rahul080327/medusa) installs without a hitch. I have managed to setup debugging using PyCharm, so I have access to breakpoint debugging functionality, if that is required.

I have a problem with running medusavm, even though it installs without a hitch. At the moment I can only access information from the console. I am running a local debug using the gcloud version of dev_appserver.py, accessed from:

```
C:/Program Files/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py
```

I have managed to successfully run the [gcloud gae tutorial app](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/tutorial/step4) using this exact setup, so I think it is a problem with the modifications I have made in my dockerfile to do with installing medusavm.

A link to the text document of my docker file is [here](http://puu.sh/fQdZx/fcce33a1d2.txt) and the console output from building from the dockerfile ( the part that I would like more info on for debugging purposes, if you know how to) is [here](http://puu.sh/fQeiz/4a341867ba.txt).

If, miraculously, you know the problem that I am facing, (which currently I do not, other than that it originates from not installing medusavm properly), that would be incredibly helpful!

Also, if you happen to know how to debug dockerfiles while using gcloud and gae, I would greatly appreciate that too.

Thank you for taking your time to read this.